# Domain Admin has no permissions to copy files onto domain share

Tags: windows, active-directory, file-sharing, share, windows-server-2008

I stumped by a problem I'm having properly accessing a domain share.

Server1: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise + the latest SP/patches. -- (Domain Controller)

Server2: Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise + the latest SP/patches -- (Part of the domain)

Machine1: Windows 7 Ultimate x64 -- (Not connected to the domain -- Just Workgroup).

So, if I share a folder on the DC (Server1) and set the permissions to allow full access for "Everyone", I cannot copy files onto this share from my Windows 7 Workgroup computer (Machine1).

Since, Server1 is part of a domain, it won't show up in Network Places... so I manually access to server via the network path "\server" and I enter the credentials for the Domain Admin: "HOME\Administrator" -- that works, and I can see all the shared folders and even copy files from the DC to my Workgroup machine, but when I try and copy a file from my Workgroup Machine to the DC, I get "Folder Access Denied" -- "You require permission from the computer's administrator to make changes to this folder"

Problem is, I'm loggin on as the Domain Admin, so I should have permission regardless.

UAC is disabled on all machines...

I have no problems transferring files from Server2 to Server1 and from Machine1 to Server2...

Any ideas?

Comment: Which permissions - file share or NTFS?  You'll need privileges in both.

Comment: Under the Security tab for the shared folder in question, Administrators (HOME\Administrators) has full control. I'm not sure what else would be needed...

Comment: Local `Administrators` group needs UAC elevation - try a different one.

Comment: The group the has permission is the Domain Admins group. Are you saying that Domain Admins also need UAC elevation... I'm able to copy onto a share on Server2 using the Domain Admin account, but cannot do so on Server1. Both servers are Win 2008 R2 machines... The only difference is that Server1 is the Domain Controller. Server2 is simply joined to the domain.

Answer (score 2):

> So, if I share a folder on the DC (Server1) and set the permissions to allow full access for "Everyone", I cannot copy files onto this share from my Windows 7 Workgroup computer

Judging by your comments, it seems that you've only set the NTFS permissions, but probably are using the default Sharing permissions, which are read-only. What you need to do is go into the Share Properties for that share and set the appropriate permissions. It's located in the Sharing tab, next to Security in the Properties window.

Generally, I grant `Everyone` Full Control in the share permissions and control access through NTFS ACLs. It's much easier to manage that way.